# Sleeping position to avoid stressing the lateral epicondyle

Tags: sleep

How can one sleep in such a way that one avoids stressing the [lateral epicondyle of the humerus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_epicondyle_of_the_humerus)? I would tend to issue that back sleeping is advised, but is there is any recommended angle for the elbow?